# searching for a "\*" in a string

Tags: python

I am trying to find the presence of a string pattern like '/*' in a string using python .
I tried a code snippet like the following :

```
strk = "*\"
if strk in num 
   print ("here it is")
```

But at the first line Ii got an error stating :

syntax error : "EOL while scanning string literal .

How to make the interpreter distinguish between "\" used as a string element and "\" as the newline character ?
I. .being inspired by the following link,  tried using

```
strk = "*(\)"
```

But this didn't work .

http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html

Comment: Did you try escaping it? `"*\\"`

Comment: Your title says `\*`, your description says `/*`, and your code does `*\`. You realize these are all completely different things, and searching for one of them isn't going to find the other two, right?

Comment: \*, /* or * which are you searching for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to make the interpreter distinguish between "\" used as a string element and "\" as the newline character ?

OK, first, `\` is not a newline character. `\n` is a newline character. And `\t` is a tab character. And so on. You've already found the whole list of them in some third-party docs, so I won't list them here.

So, how does the interpreter<sup>*</sup> distinguish between `\` meaning an actual backslash, vs. `\` meaning the first character of an escape sequence?

The rule is pretty simple:<sup>**</sup> It looks at the next character, and if it's a `n` or `t` or `x` or anything else on that list you found, then the `\` is the first character of an escape sequence; otherwise, it's just a plain backslash. (There's a separate rule for raw strings, but let's not worry about that here.<sup>***</sup>)

If you want to make sure you have a plain backslash: notice that `\\` is an escape sequence for `\`. So, just escape the backslash to make sure it's a backslash instead of an escape for something else:

```
strk = "*\\"
```

Or, to put it in terms that don't make your head hurt: Double all your backslashes in source-code string literals.

---

<sub>* Actually, by the time it gets to the interpreter, it's just a string constant object somewhere; it's the compiler that handles escape sequences. But that doesn't matter here.</sub>

<sub>** But it's not the same rule used by C. For example, in Python, `\Q` means a backslash followed by a Q, but in C, it's just the Q. Most other languages have either copied C, or just made it an error to use a backslash that isn't part of a documented escape sequence.</sub>

<sub>*** For most cases of backslash-related confusion, raw strings make everything a lot easier. But for the specific case of a backslash at the very end of the string, they instead make things slightly more confusing.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

actually you have to escape the escape backslash

```
strk = "*\\"
if strk in num:
   print ("here it is")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors seen with your code.

The first is that when write backslashes (`\`) into code, you should use two back slashes like `\\`. A single backslash is used in many languages for interpreting special characters, e.g `\n` stands for a new line and `\t` stands for tab.

The second error is with your if statement where you are missing a colon from the end of your if statement. I would also recommend you make your code like:

```
if "*\\" in word: 
   print(word)
```

where `word` could be any string.